# How to post link on Instagram feed from Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, instagram, share

I have a link & and want to post on Instagram, Facebook and Twitter feed from the Flutter app. I have used [flutter_share_me](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share_me)  plugin. but this plugin is only for Facebook and Twitter.

This is the second time I'm posting the same question.

My code:

**URL:**

```
String appUrl="https://....";
```

button for facebook:

```
IconButton(
                   icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/facebook_logo1.png",fit:BoxFit.contain,color: Colors.white,),
                   onPressed: ()async{
                     FlutterShareMe().shareToFacebook(url:appUrl,  msg: "My Flutter App");
                   },

                 ),
```

button for twitter:

```
IconButton(
                   icon: Image.asset("assets/icons/twitter_logo1.png",fit:BoxFit.fill,color: Colors.white,),
                   onPressed: ()async{
                     FlutterShareMe().shareToTwitter(url: appUrl,  msg: "My Flutter App");
                    }, 
                  )
```

Comment: You can write a http service with the api calls to [instagram](https://www.instagram.com/developer/)

Comment: Okay then, Please provide tutorial for it.

Comment: Using [Http](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data) with the Instagram API you can read and send data

Comment: But I'm using firebase. is it possible with HTTP?

Comment: You can also use this https://github.com/InstaPy/instapy-pods-server

Comment: I can't work out which of your earlier questions is a copy of this one, but please do not deliberately duplicate questions, even if it is urgent. It is a good idea to continue to work on a question even after you have asked it, and I would recommend not relying on Stack Overflow - it may not produce an answer in the timeframe you are seeking.

Comment: Okay, I understood. Actually, I'm new to Stack Overflow so don't know these kinda things. But really, It's urgent that's why I posted it again.

Answer (score 0):

did you give this package a try [share-api](https://pub.dev/packages/share_api)

Comment: But it's still in development mode and also not available for IOS.